# Flight plans affected by Gulf crisis

Tags: tickets, bookings, event-based-effects, etihad, expedia

Through Expedia, we booked a round trip ticket on Etihad Airways from Doha, Qatar to Manila, The Philippines, with one stop in Abu Dhabi. The person traveled the outbound portion and is supposed to return on June 26 through Abu Dhabi, UAE. Because of the Gulf crisis, one cannot fly from Abu Dhabi to Doha. The Etihad office in Doha is saying that Expedia has to respond and book an alternate trip with another airlines. How can we exchange the return ticket for another alternative?

Comment: You should be talking to Expedia first before coming to ask questions if there are any complications.